# Java Reflection getting message from WhatsApp by inner class on Android Notification

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-notifications, whatsapp

I´m looking for a way to get the messages from WhatsApp notifications when there is more than one line.

I´m trying to get the value from a private variable inside an inner class via Reflection in Android. I´m trying to get the 'mTexts' ArrayList of charsequence used to build an InboxStyle Notification. I'm looking for the messages from whatsapp since the last whats update there is no EXTRA on Notifications listened by notificationListener() that have the multiple lines notification (I can only get the first line).

**Any way to get the lines is worth it.**

This is my code.

```
@Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
      
     Class[] declaredClasses = sbn.getNotification().getClass().getClasses();

        for (Class c : declaredClasses){

            if(c.getName().contains("Notification$InboxStyle")){
                Class inboxStyleClass = c.getClass();

                Field[] fields = inboxStyleClass.getDeclaredFields();

                for(Field field : fields){

                    if(field.getName().contains("mText")){

                        Field fmText = null;
                        try {
                            fmText = inboxStyleClass.getDeclaredField("mTexts");
                        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        ArrayList<CharSequence> mTextsArrayList = null;

                        fmText.setAccessible(true);

                        try{
                            mTextsArrayList = (ArrayList<CharSequence>) fmText.get(**WHICH OBJECT MAY USE HERE**);
                        }catch(IllegalAccessException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        for(CharSequence value : mTextsArrayList){
                            Log.i("XXX","Results are: "+value.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }

}
```

I reach the **mText** field correctly but I can´t get the value from it.

I tried to use a new **Notification.InboxStyle()** object

```
 Notification.InboxStyle iStyleObjectToGetTheValue = new Notification.InboxStyle();
```

to see if it works well, and it does

```
inboxStyle = (ArrayList<CharSequence>) fmText.get(iStyleObjectToGetTheValue);
```

but I need the values from the notification. Any idea on how can I achieve that?

I also tried to get the message lines inflating the **RemoteViews** that you can retrieve by **StatusBarNotification.getNotification().THE_REMOTE_VIEW** because using *DeviceMonitor* you can take an screenshot of the device and see the IDs of the views... but had no lucky with that.

**Any way to get the lines is worth it.**

All the help is welcomed!
Thanks!

Comment: Can't you get contentView/bigContentView from the notification and inspect them to find the text?

Comment: How can I inspect the remote views? -I tried to search by getting the view nodes but didn´t find anything reliable... maybe i did wrong....

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs for RemoteView.apply():

> View apply(Context context, ViewGroup parent) - Inflates the view hierarchy represented by this object and applies all of the actions.

You can create a parent and provide the context to `RemoteView.apply()`. Inspect the resulting View to find the text:

```
@Nullable
public View getBigContentView (StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification) {
    RemoteViews bigContentView = statusBarNotification.getNotification().bigContentView;
    return bigContentView != null ? bigContentView.apply(ctx, null) : null;
}
```

This might not work in Nougat phones, as according to the documentation (reading this more carefully tells me that Google probably did not mean for you to read this parameter and that it should only be used when building the notification):

> ```
>  * As of N, this field may be null. The expanded notification view is determined by the
>  * inputs to {@link Notification.Builder}; a custom RemoteViews can optionally be
>  * supplied with {@link Notification.Builder#setCustomBigContentView(RemoteViews)}.
> ```

Comment: I´m getting null pointer when trying to inflate bigContentView(). This is my code...  RemoteViews rv = sbn.getNotification().bigContentView;
        LayoutInflater inflater =   (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewGroup localView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(rv.getLayoutId(), null);
        rv.reapply( ctx.getApplicationContext(), localView);

        for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)localView).getChildCount(); ++i){
            View nextChild = ((ViewGroup) localView).getChildAt(i);
            Log.i("XXX","ID: "+nextChild.getId());
        }

Comment: No lucky with that... Can´t see anything to work with... Only 2 IDs with no interest. How can I know wich view belong this IDs?